# Displaying value in infopath not the number

Tags: infopath, lookup-column, dropdown

[image]

Infopath. In my infopath form. I want to show the teamName as "team 1" value  but it is displaying "1" number instead of "team 1". The TeamName is a lookup column in the ProjectList.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing similar issue where i am unable to pull value. I have changed the value Field from ID to value but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I you are using a SharePoint list which has a column as a lookup column which then looks up another list, Ensure this column is Pulling the "Title" not the ID.

Answer (score 1):

This link may help you guys..
http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/11/get-infopath-to-display-lookup-column-value-not-id/

Comment: Please add a summary of the solution to your answer. Link only answers are not helpful forever, as links tend to break over time.

Answer (score 0):

Value should be TeamID and name should be TeamName.
It works like normal asp dropdown where you specify id as datavaluefield and text as datatextfield.